# prolog lists of lists domain and labeling

Tags: list, dns, prolog, clpfd, labeling

> L=[[X,Y,Z],[1,A,B],[2,C,D]], L ins 1..3, all_different(L), label(L).

I just want to fill the variables in the lists of the list with values. Is there any solution to get the elements of the list (which are lists) in an easier way than `get_element_at(L,1)` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

```
get_element(LL,M,N,Element) :-
        length([_|L01],M),
        length([_|L02],N),
        append(L01,[L|_],LL),
        append(L02,[Element|_],L).
```